# How to get the correct context within this custom view?

Tags: android, view, android-context

I am making a "scratch ticket" type view but which is scratching away a black and white overlay to reveal color, and I am trying to allow for the deprecation of getDrawable, but I am confused over the context. My code is:

```
public class ScratchView extends View{....

    public void setOverlay(int id)
    {
        Bitmap orig = Bitmap.createBitmap(gameWidth, gameHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
        Drawable tDrawable;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            tDrawable = mActivity.getResources().getDrawable(id, context.getTheme());
        } else {
            tDrawable = mActivity.getResources().getDrawable(id);
        }
```

What is the correct command to get the context for versions of lollipop and later?

Comment: You can use getContext()

Comment: mariozawa, please add as answer and I will set as correct

Answer (score 0):

When You are making a new class that derives from **View**, 
You have to create constructor matching super.
So You can get context.

```
public class ScratchView extends View {

    public ScratchView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ContextCompat to avoid evaluating the version of Android.

The context for a view is normally the context of your Activity, which is the same activity.

From a fragment you can get the context of the activity using getContext().

[ContextCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use getContext() from View class. Every class extending View like LinearLayout, RelativeLayout etc has this.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext()

Or you can initialize context on your default constructors

```
public AwesomeView(Context context) {
     mContext = context;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1.create MyApplication, declear MyApplication in AndroidManifest.xml

public class MyApplication extends Application {

```
public static MyApplication instances;
@Override    public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    instances = this;

}
public static MyApplication getInstances(){
    return instances;
}
```

}

2.use these codes in ScratchView

```
    MyApplication myApplication = MyApplication.getInstances();
    myApplication.getApplicationContext();//this is the context you want
```